# Join not giving expected result

Tags: join, left-join

Attached my source table and expected output and actual output received in the screenshot after performing self left join.
[image]

Issue when the main table has a record for logon and doesnt recieve a record for logoff or logon expired, then the join is not returning the record with Request ID '5'.

Pasted the code below used in image2[image]

I am stuck at this point and not able to proceed further, Please let me know where am I goin wrong and provide your suggestions

Thnaks,
Mani

Comment: Are you sure the cogipf_status values are all 'Success'?

Comment: cogipf_status can have null , success and Failure values, but we are interested only on Success values.